# Some odd, some even

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

What's the four-word phrase I'm *most likely* looking for? **(6) (2) (3) (4)**

Try figure it out!

```
        * * * * *   *      
    *   * * * * * * *  
    * * * *   * *   *
    * * * * * * * * *
    * * * * * * * * *
    *     * * * * * *
    *   * * * * * * *
    * * * * * * * * *
    *   * *   * *   *
    * * * * * * * * *
    * * * * * * * * *
    *   * *     *   *
    *   * * * * *   *
    * * * * * *   *
    *   * *   *   *
        * *   * *   *
    *   * *   * * * *
    * * * * * * *   *
        * *   * *
    *   * *   * *
    * * * * * * * * *
    * * * *   * * * *
    * * * *   * * * *
    *   * * * * * * *
    * * * * * * * * *
    * * * * * * * * *
    * * * * * * *
    * * * * * * * * *
    *   * *       *
    * * * * * *   *
    *   * * * * *   *
    * * * *   * *   *
    *   * * * *   *
    * *   * * * * * *
    *   * * * * * 
    * *   * * * * * *

 


  {_||}    {|_|_}  {||\}
      
     
  {_|_}    {_|_ _} {_|_|_}
     
     
  {|/|\}   {|_|_}  {|_|_\}


  {|_|_}   {||_ _} {|_|_\}

  
  {|/|\}   {|_|_}  {/|\}

     
  {_||}    {||_}   {||\}

     
  {_||}    {||_}   {_|}

     
  {|_|_}   {||_}   {_ _|_|}

     
  {|_|_ _} {_|_ _} {||_ _}

     
  {_ _||}  {_ _ |} {|_}

     
  {||\}    {_ _||} {/\}


  {_ _/|\} {_|_ _} {_ _ |}
```

Comment: +1! *Even* I'll call it *odd* ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the phrase is

> Months of the year

Because

> The asterisks, when interpreted as 3x3 characters, form `JAN` to `DEC`
> [image]

And

> The contents inside the brackets can be used to make the corresponding letter in ASCII art, e.g. `{|/|\}` = `|\/|`

Comment: That's it! Your answer is correct and that's the phrase I had in mind. My idea with the bottom characters was that they represented rot13(rvgure n ubevfbagny, iregvpny be qvntbany yvar. Fb qvqa'g znxr gurz cerpvfr nf lbh pna frr. Nf sbe gur gvgyr, V whfg zrnag fbzr zbaguf unir bqq ahzore bs qnlf, fbzr rira ahzore bs qnlf.) Well done!